# combination time table generate

Tags: php, combinations, timetable

I want generate time table with combination

I have 3 tables in mysql

```
1. subjects
sub_id, sub_name;

2. staff
staff_id, staff_name;

3. sub_staff
sub_id, staff_id, sub_count;
```

weekly
    sub1 = 6 class
    sub2 = 4 class
    sub3 = 4 class

total weekly classes = 42

daily periods = 7

Comment: Personally I can't work out what you're asking or what you've provided. Can you perhaps try rewording / be more descriptive with the problem?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: I want college time table; we are conduct daily 7  periods weekly 6 day so 7*6 = 42 three subjects in the syllabus we conduct weekly sub1 = 6 classes, sub2 = 4 classes and sub3 = 4 classes.  I want daily and weekly timetable